# Getting unknown server error when I set CORS setting correctly from MS Doc

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular8, asp.net-core-3.1

I was getting 405 Method Not allowed but now I am getting 0 Unknown Error after setting CORS to the controller and `start.cs`. I am focusing on Error_connection_refused. Why is it refusing? The Tech stack is Angular 8 + asp.net core 3.1

[image]

Comment: Which MS Doc? A link?

Answer (score 0):

I change the order of pipe line on `Startup.cs` now it's working beautifully. Just in case to whom it may struggle with this. I put the solution here. I have used asp.net 3.1

**Configure***

```
 app.UseExceptionHandler(
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.Run(
                          async context =>
                          {
                              context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                              context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                              var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                              if (error != null)
                              {
                                  context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                                  await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                              }
                          });
                    });
```